# Find File Upload URL using Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to find upload URL of any of the (gmail/yahoo/outlook) email providers using wireshark. I have tried the following filter and tried to see where I go but in vein.

```
ip.addr == MY_IP_ADDRESS && http
```

I have tried to **Follow TCP Stream**, **Follow HTTP Stream** on several http packets but, again, I could not find the upload url of a file.

How do I find file upload URL of any of the above email providers? Thanks for any input.

========== **EDIT** ===============

Guys...I actually have this POST request URL. See below

```
`char* gmail_pattern = "(?sU)^POST https://mail.google.com/mail/.*view=up.*Content-Disposition: attachment..filename=\"(.*)\"";`
```

It is just that I don't know how to generate this. Most likely, this is not dynamic. I was given this code and I don't know how to regenerate it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What file upload are you referring to?

Comment: @meatspace....please view my edited question. When user hits a button to upload files, I want to capture that POST request.

Comment: Assuming you are the user and you just want the (dynamically generated), so not very useful) URL of the file that you uploaded, you can do something like `ip.host contains "mail.google.com"` and watch it while you upload something.

Comment: Plz see my edited question. I tried your solution but it didn't work. Wireshark doesn't show anything at all.